# Isomorphism between line bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, riemann-surfaces

I encounter the following problem:
Let $E$ be a line bundle, prove that the tensor of $E$ and $E$'s dual is isomorphic to a trivial line bundle.

I feel it should be easy since every line bundle is locally like a one-dimensional space and the dual of it is just a scalar multiplication, but I can't write down the details. Does anyone can give a detailed solution of this problem?

Comment: Do you know about transition functions? If so, how do you give the transition functions of $E^*$ in terms of the transition functions of $E$? Alternatively, can you give a nowhere-zero global section? By the way, if you search the site you will find this discussed several other places.

Comment: This is tagged in riemman-surfaces and AG, so one can assume that you mean complex line bundles over a riemann surface? If this is true, then it should be stated in your question

Comment: By the way, one algebraic way to see this is to note that by the usual vector space isomorphism $$V \otimes V^* \cong \mathrm{Hom}(V,V)$$ we can see that there are bundle isomorphisms of the same type. Since the latter has a global nonvanishing section (the identity map) you can deduce that the tensor of a line bundle and its dual is trivial.

Comment: @Tedshifrin Yes, I do know the transition functions, the transition function of E^* is ((g_ij)^t )^{-1} if the transition function of E is g_ij. And I searched but found nothing...

Comment: @Sherose then you are very close :) ! Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @AndresMejia Yes, we consider the complex case and sorry for the lack of this statement...

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1290233/geometrically-why-do-line-bundles-have-inverses-with-respect-to-the-tensor-prod/1290427#1290427) is one discussion from the past.

Comment: @AndresMejia Since I found that the definition of isomorphism between vector bundles is defined as a "normal" isomorphism i.e. E and F are isomorphism if there exists an isomorphism between E and F. But in this definition, there is nothing to do with gluing map...That's where I get stuck....

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Sherose I think that it will help to look at [these notes](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~azinger/mat566-spr15/vectorbundles.pdf)

Comment: @AndresMejia Thank you very much!